# Access Denied Error in SHarepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When deploying asolution containing webparts to a Sharepoint 2010 webite I get the following error message:

```
Add Solution:
  Adding solution 'User_Controls.wsp'...
  Deploying solution 'User_Controls.wsp'...
Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\CONTROLTEMPLATES\MyProject\CompanyInformation.ascx' is denied.
```

When I try to access the MyProject folder through windows explorer I can't see the contents and get an access denied error:

```
[Window Title]
Location is not available

[Content]
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\Toyota is not accessible.

Access is denied.


[OK]
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are deploying a Sandbox solution and not a Farm Solution.

**Edit:** if you can try making iisreset and try deploying again.

Comment: Sandbox Solution is set to false, what should it be, I don't think we are using a sandboxed solution

Answer (score 1):

Can you check whether there is read permission given to everyone for the physical folder 'ControlTemplates' or 'MyProject' ? If not, you can assign permissions and redeploy the solution.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing giving the everyone user al permissions on the control templates folder, but it keeps loosing permissions, I just want to find out why.

Comment: when are you losing the permissions? did you try deploying before losing the permissions?

Answer (score 1):

To perform farm wide operations (like adding and deploying solutions) you should be member of administrators group on the machine. Note that you may need to "run as administrator" to have required permissions.